# UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform

Tags: java

Not able to load .dll file from JDK 1.8.60 32 bit. On system of 32 bit. Where same .dll gets loaded successfully on same system of 32 bit with JDK 1.6 32 bit.

Where is it failing ?

Comment: If you use a 32 bit system, then you need a 32 bit DLL; you won't be able to load a 64 bit DLL.

Comment: Thanks Mark, One of the .dll file among set was of 64Bit. that's why error was occurring. But now there is different error occurring as "UnsatisfiedLinkError: __CreateObject(ZZ)Z

Comment: That means none of the native dependencies provide a required method.